# Clojure "Game of Life"

Tags: beginner, clojure, game-of-life

I'm a Clojure beginner and I implemented [Game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) to learn how I should code things in Clojure.

```
(def state (ref [
    [false false false false false]
    [false false true  false false]
    [false false true  false false]
    [false false true  false false]
    [false false false false false]]))

(defn get-state [state x y]
  (nth (nth state y) x))

(defn count-true-neighbours [state x y]
  (let [size (count state)]
    (->>
      (for [p (range (- x 1) (+ x 2))
            q (range (- y 1) (+ y 2))
            :when (not (and (= x p) (= y q)))]
        [p q])
      (map (fn [coord]
        (let [[p q] coord]
          (if (or (< p 0) (>= p size) (< q 0) (>= q size))
            false
            (get-state state p q)))))
      (filter true?)
      (count))))

(defn next-state-of [state x y]
  (let [alive (get-state state x y)
        alive-neighbours (count-true-neighbours state x y)]
    (cond
      (and (not alive) (= alive-neighbours 3)) true
      (and alive (or (= alive-neighbours 2) (= alive-neighbours 3))) true
      :else false)))

(defn next-state [state]
  (let [size (count state)]
    (mapv
      (fn [row]
        (mapv
          #(next-state-of state %1 row)
          (range 0 size)))
      (range 0 size))))

(defn pretty-print [state]
  (let [size (count state)]
    (loop [i 0]
      (if (< i size)
        (do
          (println
            (->>
              (nth state i)
              (mapv #(if %1 "■ " "□ "))
              (reduce str)))
          (recur (inc i)))))))

(defn tick
  ([times] (tick 0 times))
  ([i times]
    (if (< i times)
      (do
        (dosync
          (println (str i ":"))
          (pretty-print @state)
          (ref-set state (next-state @state)))
        (recur (inc i) times))
      nil)))

(defn -main [& args]
  (tick 5))
```

I used `ref` to learn how to manage state although it seems like an overkill for this tiny program.

As you see my code is terrible, but I couldn't improve this by myself.

I already checked [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/17603/critique-my-clojure-game-of-life-code) answer, but I think I did this in a quite different way and need a different advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code actually isn't *terrible*, but there are a few places where it can be improved.

---

First, the `ref`. It's entirely unnecessary in this case. What I'd change to keep everything immutable:

Change your declaration at the top to just:

```
(def initial-state [[false false false false false]
                    [false false true  false false]
                    [false false true  false false]
                    [false false true  false false]
                    [false false false false false]])
```

This now defines, as the name suggests, the *initial* state of the game. This will no longer be used to store the running state.

Now, you can change `tick` to get rid of the need for `ref-set`:

```
(defn tick [state times]
  (loop [i 0 ; Moved the counter into a loop
         acc-state state] ; Keeping track of the running state
   (when (< i times)
     (println (str i ":"))
     (pretty-print acc-state)

     ; Recur into the loop instead of the function itself
     (recur (inc i) (next-state acc-state)))))

(defn -main [& args]
  (tick initial-state 5))
```

Note how I just made the running state an accumulator of a `loop`. I think the whole design should be rethought though. Really, you could just get the successive states by using `iterate`, and `take` as many as you want. Lets say you want to get the first five states after the `initial-state`:

```
(take 5 (iterate next-state initial-state))
```

Now, your entire `tick` function can basically be written as:

```
; Obviously, change 5 to however many states you want to produce
(doseq [state (take 5 (iterate next-state initial-state))]
  (pretty-print state))
```

---

I would change `pretty-print` to a `format` style function that returns a string instead of printing directly. That way, the caller can make use of your prettying, but decide how/when they want to display it.

---

Your `count-true-neighbors` function is huge. I'd break it down into a few discreet parts:

- You have a part that produces a list of neighbors to check
- You have a part that does bounds checking

I'd change it to something more like:

```
(defn neighbors-of [x y]
  (for [p (range (- x 1) (+ x 2))
        q (range (- y 1) (+ y 2))
        :when (not (and (= x p) (= y q)))]
    [p q]))

(defn inbounds? [x y size]
  (and (<= 0 x (dec size)) ; Comparison operators can be chained!
       (<= 0 y (dec size))))

(defn count-true-neighbours [state x y]
  (let [size (count state)]
    (->> (neighbors-of x y)
      (map (fn [[p q]] ; You can deconstruct here directly
             (when (inbounds? p q size)
               (get-state state p q))))
      (filter true?)
      (count))))
```

Your `map`ping function could be changed to:

```
(map (fn [[p q]]
       (and (inbounds? p q size)
            (get-state state p q))))
```

Although the benefit here is subjective.

Things to note:

- `<=` and other comparison operators can be used to check more than two arguments! I'm making use of that in `inbounds?` to neaten it up a bit.
- I reduced your bounds check in the map down to `(when (inbounds? p q size) ...)`. `when` returns `nil` (falsey) if the condition fails, so you don't need to explicitly return `false`.

---

```
(or (= alive-neighbours 2) (= alive-neighbours 3)))
```

Can also be written as:

```
(#{2 3} alive-neighbors)
```

It's a matter of style which you prefer. I prefer the latter personally.

---

```
(nth (nth state y) x))
```

Can also be written as:

```
(get-in state [y x])
```

---

There's a few things to note in `pretty-print`:

```
(reduce str strings)
```

Isn't *wrong*, but a more idiomatic way of writing it would be:

```
(apply str strings)
```

With:

```
(mapv #(if %1 "■ " "□ "))
```

You add explicit spaces after the display characters. It may be cleaner to use `join` to add the spaces. This limits the repetition, and gets rid of the trailing space. This also lets you just use the character literals directly.

And when you use threading macros (`->>`), you put the expression being threaded on the next line. Personally, I prefer to put the threaded expression on the same line as the `->>`. This makes it clearer what's being threaded.

Taking that all together, I'd write that whole bit as:

```
(->> (nth state i)
     (mapv #(if %1 \■ \□))
     (s/join " ")
     (apply str)))
```

Where `s` is an alias for `clojure.string`.